# I was on "restart in not available on wayland" screen. I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F7 and got this black screen

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Here's an image of a black screen. I'm getting this input line blinking repeatedly.

[image: Here's the picture of black screen. I'm getting this input line blinking repeatedly]

Comment: Try Alt+f2 to get back to the normal X screen, or Alt+f1 for the login screen. From X use the ctl_alt_f? to select one of the virtual terminals, which offer a login if nothing is else is running on it (or nothing if no login is running on it, like f7)

Comment: Alt+f2 combined with ctrl worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Alt+f2 to get back to the normal X screen, or Alt+f1 for the login screen. From X use the ctl_alt_f? to select one of the virtual terminals, which offer a login if nothing is else is running on it (or nothing if no login is running on it, like f7)